# Dropdown menu flickering on hover after updating to Chrome 45

Tags: css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, hover

Seeing a weird bug on a site I'm working on, I was using Chrome 44 and the bug was reported by a user who had updated to 45. When hovering on dropdown menus the links flicker and get offset see screenshot:

[image]

I tested on 44 and couldn't see it but after updating it turned up. I'm guessing there's just a CSS `:hover` rule that needs sorting out but I wanted to ask if anyone else has seen similar issues when updating to Chrome 45? [Here's a link to the live site](http://www.jasminesilk.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved just by adding `position: relative` to all dropdown links hover states in case anyone else gets this bug:

```
#lists li:hover a {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Out of interest, I wonder if using a `<dl>` without a reference to a child `<dd>` is causing issues? Because it almost looks like the browser duplicates the element on hover or something.

Comment: hmm yeh maybe, there is a dt but maybe dl's expect dd's. It does look like it's being duplicated but I cant tell whether thats just the hover state being switched on and off very quickly and offsetting it or js duplicating it

Comment: `dl`s are meant to have 2 children: `dt` and `dd`. Just using a regular `ul` with a `li` child could be a little nicer perhaps (but I'm not sure if you even need a list in this particular case).

Comment: hmm yeh true, I'm working with legacy markup from a php template that cant be changed because it's used across 150 sites though sadly

Comment: Fair enough. "Ideal" isn't always feasible!